# Java Windowbuilder Changing a Window Builder Class with another Class

Tags: java, windowbuilder

It's my first question here.
As the title already says, this question is about Java Windowbuilder and about a project I am currently working on.

So:
I got a class creating an Window using Window Builder with multiple `RadioButton`s each with a unique name.
I need a second class, which I "inherit" (already needed to inherit `JFrame`) by simulating it with interfaces.
In this second class I need to be able to change e.g. the RadioButtons in the first class.

Maybe I just do not see the solution...

Comment: First class (with UI):  function updateUI(String text){ RadioButton.setText(text); }  Second class:  FirstClass class = new FirstClass(); class.updateUI("Some stuff"); ?

Comment: It would be best if you post your code here.